# How to handle a route and a 'child route' in SammyJS?

Tags: regex, sammy.js

I am building a page, that based on two routes, loads up some panels. Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a list of cases listed on the page. If I visit http://example.com/#case/1, I want to display information about the case with id=1.

And if I visit http://example.com/#case/1/item/1 I want to display both information about the case with id=1, but also information about the item with id=1.

So far I have the following routes setup:

```
this.get('#case/:id', function () {
   console.log('case route');
});

this.get('#/case/:caseId/item/:itemId', function () {
    console.log('item route');
});
```

If I visit the links mentioned above, the first link displays the case information just fine. But if I visit the second link, both routes are triggered. First the item route, and then the case route. But I wont nessesarily execute the same block of code when working on the item route.

How can I tell Sammy to only handle one or the other route - eventhough part of the route matches the .get() route ?

I could build a regular expression with capture groups, but how do I access the capture groups from within the get function?

```
this.get(/\#case\/(\d)+/, function() {
    //Use case id somehow
});
```

Comment: Now I cant get Sammy to run both routes. So I guess the behaviour was because of a bug I had somewhere else.

Comment: To answer my own question about capture groups in regexp routes:
You can access capture groups by accessing this.params.splat